# Converting access query to oracle (sub joins)

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I'm stuck at this point trying to convert the following access query to oracle.
The error I'm getting at this point is `SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis` though maybe the cause is something else?
If I remove the IIf line completely I still get the same error.

```
SELECT Table01.Land
FROM Table01 
RIGHT JOIN (Table02 
RIGHT JOIN ((Table03
LEFT JOIN Table04 ON Table03.ARTNR = Table04.ARTNR)
LEFT JOIN Table05 ON Table03.ARTNR = Table05.ARTNR) ON Table02.Vertreter = Table05.VERTRNR) ON Table01.Land = Table05.LAND
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to put your joins together is this way based on the relationships you provided.

```
FROM Table01 
LEFT JOIN Table05 ON Table01.Land = Table05.LAND
RIGHT JOIN Table02 ON Table02.Vertreter = Table05.VERTRNR
RIGHT JOIN Table03 ON Table03.ARTNR = Table05.ARTNR 
LEFT JOIN Table04 ON Table03.ARTNR = Table04.ARTNR
```

Comment: I've marked this as answer because I've used this example to work out the query. Thanks all for helping out.

Answer (score 1):

In your query, the main table is `Table03`. From it you perform a series of outer joins to other tables. The simplest way of transforming the join into Oracle is:

```
SELECT
    Table03.KONZERN, Table05.FIRMNR, Table05.ARTNR, Table05.FORM, 
    Table05.Au, Table05.PRKW, Table05.LFKW, Table05.KNDKBZ, 
    Table05.AUFTRNR, Table05.LIEFNR, Table05.LAND, Table05.GAT, 
    Table05.KOMMI, Table05.TRNR, Table05.KNDNR, Table04.PlaZ, 
    Table03.GF, Table04.GP, Table05.ARTNR2, Table05.von_AF, 
    Table04.EU, Table04.NA,
    -- the following line needs to be changed to: CASE WHEN ELSE END
    IIf(Table01.Land_2, IIf(Table02.Vertreter>="0", Vertreter_Land,Land_2)) AS LAND2,
    Table01.Land, Table02.Vertreter_Land
  FROM Table03 
  LEFT JOIN Table04 ON Table03.ARTNR = Table04.ARTNR
  LEFT JOIN Table05 ON Table03.ARTNR = Table05.ARTNR
  LEFT JOIN Table02 ON Table02.Vertreter = Table05.VERTRNR
  LEFT JOIN Table01 ON Table01.Land = Table05.LAND
```

**Note**: I don't really know how the `IIF()` functions works exactly. Most likely you can replace it with a standard `CASE WHEN END` in SQL.